# How to set dynamic take profit but static stop loss in pinescript v4?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I've been having some problems with the stop function in Pinescript v4. The TP works but for some reason, the stop isn't working. Attached is the code snippet and a picture of where it should be.

[Stop should be at the highest high of the last 4 bars (including the current bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ckx.png)

```
longstop = lowest(low, 4)
shortstop = highest(high, 4)

if longcond
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 5, stop = longstop)
strategy.exit("TP", "long", limit = EMA)
if shortcond
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 5, stop = shortstop)
strategy.exit("TP", "short", limit = EMA)
```

Update

If I add an extra strategy.exit() function within the if block, then it will only trigger when it hits the stop price even when it should have closed at the limit price [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzLVC.png)

```
 if shortcond
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 5)
    strategy.exit("SL", "short", stop = shortstop)
strategy.exit("TP", "short", limit = EMA)
```

If I add the stop to the current strategy.exit() line, then the stop price is continually updated at each bar for the lowest/highest of the past 4 bars which I don't want. I want the stop price to be set and static at the entry bar.

```
if longcond
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 5)
 
strategy.exit("TP", "long", limit = EMA, stop = longstop)
```

**I want the TP to be dynamic (updates every bar to be the EMA price) but I want the SL to be static (the lowest/highest price within the last 4 bars)**

Answer (score 0):

`limit` argument of the `strategy.exit()` is used for take profits. If you want to set a stop loss, use the `stop` argument.

Comment: Updated the original post with more info. By adding the stop to the current strategy.exit() line I get the problem of the stop price continually changing each bar when I want it to remain static.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding a condition counting the number of bars since entry and switching to v5.

```
shortstop = ta.highest(5)
longstop = ta.lowest(5)

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 50, when = longcond)
longbarsSinceEntry = bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0)
strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop = longstop[longbarsSinceEntry], limit = EMA)


strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 50,  when = shortcond)
shortbarsSinceEntry = bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0)
strategy.exit("exit", "short", stop = shortstop[shortbarsSinceEntry], limit = EMA)
```